# Mysql 5.6 on 16.04 missing config files

Tags: mysql

I've got mysql 5.6 installed and working on 16.04 however it appears many of the standard configuration files are not present or the configuration changes are ignored. I've googled the heck out of this problem and tried several suggested fixes before posting here.

`/etc/my.cnf` (does not exist. Tried creating it and adding configs to no avail)

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (empty except for !includedir `/etc/mysql/conf.d`)

Added section header [`mysqld`] 
Added config changes

- max_allowed_packet=34M
- innodb_log_file_size=2GB

Ignored on startup (SELECT `@@max_allowed_packet; returns 4194304 default`) and application (Confluence) complains about settings.

`/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` (empty except for header section [`mysql`]) Configs added here are ignored also even under section header [`mysqld`].

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

TIA

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION IN THE EDIT SECTION**

I know the reason, I'm still trying to find a solution for this.

Just to be sure if your situation is like mine, run:

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

you should see most of the packages in version 5.6.x, except a couple, especially mysql-common which is 5.7.x.

As specified from the description of the package:

> MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Basically, any mysql-x-5.6 depends on mysql-common, which in this case comes from the main repository so it's for 5.7, and if you try to manually install mysql-common-5.6 it will either conflict or depend on mysql-common (because in the previous Ubuntu versions it was 5.6).

I still haven't found a solution for this, but maybe with this additional info someone can come up with one.

**EDIT:** I found a solution, it seems to be the easiest.
First off, remove all mysql packages and files (backup the important ones):

```
apt purge mysql*
apt autoremove
apt autoclean
rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

You should now be clean.

Now go [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html#downloads) and download the version you need, it contains all the dependencies except libaio1, so:

```
apt install libaio1
tar -xvf downloadedMysqlPackage.tar
dpkg -i mysql-common-xxx.deb
dpkg-preconfigure mysql-community-server-xxx.deb
dpkg -i mysql-community-server-xxx.deb
dpkg -i mysql-community-client-xxx.deb
dpkg -i libmysqlclient18-xxx.deb
```

And you're good to go!